# Python numpy: skip calculation on (math-) error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d-numpy-array and need to do some maths on it. There are divisions, exponentiations and root extractions. Since I do not hold control over the input that is in the array, numpy is bound to run into a bunch of math errors.

At the moment, I am trying to catch all the possible exceptions, but there are just too many and I can never be sure if I get all of them for every possible szenario and each of the 50+ formulas. My intention is to initialize the output-matrix with nodata-values and that numpy leaves them in place when an error occurs.

Given the following example as a 1d-representation (numpy imported as np):

```
a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40], dtype=np.float16) # my data source
b = np.full(shape=(4,3), fill_value=-999, dtype=np.float16) # shape: length =4, no. of different calculations=3
b[:,0] = a / (a-10)
b[:,1] = a**200
b[:,2] = np.sqrt(a-40)
```

If I run the code like this, I get three RuntimeWarning (division by zero, overflow and invalid value in sqrt). Still, my b-array is filled with results:

```
b[:,0] -> [ inf 2. 1.5 1.333 ]
b[:,1] -> [ inf inf inf inf ]
b[:,2] -> [ nan nan nan 0. ]
```

Instead I would like numpy to skip the calculation and leave the initialized value in place, so that I would get

```
b[:,0] -> [ -999. 2. 1.5 1.333 ]
b[:,1] -> [ -999. -999. -999. -999. ]
b[:,2] -> [ -999. -999. -999. 0. ]
```

I could later convert inf or nan to -999 but that's another iteration and time consuming.  I also found `np.seterr(all='ignore')` but that simply supresses the output to my console.

Comment: Have a look at NumPy [`masked arrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)